# How to work with JSON_EXTRACT in Maria Db Version 10.1.18

Tags: mysql, version, mariadb

I have a mysql query which is not working on MariaDb 10.1.18 as it contains a 
function "json_extract" and it is not available in this version but in 10.2.3.

So how i can I use this functin in this version?
Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting a value out of the JSON?  Or are you getting the value to test it?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you upgrade your MariaDB to 10.2 using this steps in official documentation: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/upgrading-from-mariadb-101-to-mariadb-102/

If you're using json_extract() for simple JSONs, you can look at extract_json_value() method in *common_schema*.